# Turtle Python Package Could Not Be Installed On Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-turtle

As you can see below, The turtle package could not be install on the machine and raised errors and even note that i've install python-tk package on ubuntu, how could i solve the problem?
[image: Turtle Python Package]

Comment: That implies that pip is trying to install a version of turtle written for a completely different Python release. But you shouldn't _need_ to use pip to install turtle at all --  it's included out-of-the-box in Python 3; no installation needed. Just skip the step altogether.

Comment: (Reading https://pypi.org/project/turtle/, the pypi project "turtle" is completely different from the Turtle graphics library that uses python-tk -- and it dates back to 2009, so it's _definitely_ not made for modern Python)

Comment: BTW, note that `python-tk` is for Python **2**. You probably want `python3-tk`.

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libpython3.10-stdlib/filelist, demonstrating that turtle is included in `libpython3.10-stdlib` on Ubuntu (and presumably its equivalents for other versions as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You don't need to install `turtle` at all

The `turtle` graphics library built on top of python-tk is part of the Python 3 standard library. It doesn't require installation: It's *already included* with Python 3.

The thing `pip` is trying to install is a much older library with the same name but built for a completely different purpose, which was never updated to be compatible with Python 3 in the first place.

Just `import turtle`. You don't need to install anything first.

(That said, note that you need `python3-tk`, not `python-tk`, to use turtle with Python 3).

---

To demonstrate the above, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libpython3.10-stdlib/filelist, listing the files included in `libpython3.10-stdlib` for the Jammy release of Ubuntu; you'll see `/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py` included.